# Different runtime of LOF

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, elki

I am using Elki for running LOF algorithm but every time i run LOF algorithm in Elki, Elki is giving different runtime on same data set. 
I am confused why is this happening?

Comment: How big is the difference? You realize that runtimes vary because of e.g. GUI, IO, Garbage Collection, thermal throttling of CPUs, and many other factors?

Comment: 3329ms apprx difference on every run and difference also varying. No, i was not aware of that factors.

Comment: Out of what total?

Comment: Once i run Elki gave 62581 ms runtime but second time when i run than runtime was 65910 ms so the difference of both is 3329

Comment: 5% is larger than I would have expected, but not surprising with Java and modern CPUs. You CPU may be able to boost its clock speed by 10%, but it may be unable to sustain this very long because of heat.

Answer (score 0):

As @Anony-Mousse mentioned in the comments, getting reliable runtime values is hard.

This is not specific to ELKI - the LOF algorithm does not involve randomness, so one would assume that you get the same runtime every time. But in reality, you just don't get the same result every time.

Here are some hints on getting more reliable runtimes:

1. Do **not** run multiple experiments in the same process. Start a **fresh JVM** for each (otherwise, it will likely have to **garbage collect** the objects of the previous run at some time otherwise).
2. Runtime differences of less than 1 second are not significant. To measure runtimes of say less than a second, you should rather use specialized tools such as [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/).
3. Run several times, and use the **median value, or a truncated mean**.
4. **Disable turbo boost**, and make sure your CPU is well cooled. On Linux (and I would suggest that you use a dedicated Linux system for benchmarking!), you can disable CPU boost via:

   ```
   echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo
   ```

   My CPU has a 3.4 GHz base clock, but can boost to 3.9 GHz. That is 15% faster, but it cannot run 3.9 Ghz when using all cores. Depending on the number of threads running, the actual clock could be 3.4, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9 GHz; and it could even temporarily decide to throttle down to even 1.6 GHz. So you may even need to monitor your CPU clock speeds (e.g. see `grep "^cpu MHz" /proc/cpuinfo`). But definitely disable to turbo boost.
5. Do **not** use `-verbose`. Logging has a noticeable impact on runtime.
6. Do **not** use the MiniGUI. Notice that the MiniGUI displays a **command line** for you to copy, like `KDDCLIApplication -dbc.in file.csv -algorithm ...` that allows you to run the experiment from console, without GUI overhead.
7. Do not use visualization. Visualization needs a lot of memory, and CPU, and that will have a measureable impact. ELKI tries to measure the algorithm time independently, and then visualize afterwards; but there might still be some memory cleanup in the background even if you have closed the visualization window. Preferably, for runtime benchmarking, **use `-resulthandler DiscardResultHandler`** to discard the actual result; and get the timinig from the `-time` log (the log should be only a few lines long; avoid excessive output)

Comment: than i should use "Elki CLI"?

Comment: Yes, using the command line interface is more reliable, because you have a fresh JVM each time and no UI overhead.

Comment: Given file data\synthetic\Vorlesung\mickey-mouse.csv for parameter "dbc.in" does not exist!
I dont know what the do with this issue. Kindly guide.

Comment: The following parameters were not processed: [data/synthetic/Vorlesung/mickey-mouse.csv]
The following configuration errors prevented execution:

Given file data\synthetic\Vorlesung\mickey-mouse.csv for parameter "dbc.in" does not exist!

Error instantiating internal class: de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.workflow.InputStep


Stopping execution because of configuration errors.
this is the complete error which eclipse is showing and i just imported elki project and syned with gradle and then hit the run button and eclipse showed the above error and mickey-mouse.csv is not not found on github too.

Comment: Yes, because the file was renamed. You need to fix the file name.

Comment: The "ELKI CLI" launch configuration contained the old file name. It is an example configuration, you need to modify it (unless you only ever want to use the mouse example data set...)

Comment: i pasted my csv file in elki-project\data\synthetic\Vorlesung folder and gave -dbc covtype.data as argurment but eclipse is giving error "Class not found for given value. Must be a subclass / implementation of de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.datasource.DatabaseConnection". Kindly guide how i can get rid of this error.

Comment: Don't paste files randomly and mix random command line parameters and expect that to work. The `-dbc` parameter has a description: "Database connection class." - it requires a *class*. You probably meant `-dbc.in`? With command line, you need to be precise, it will not guess what you maybe wanted... But as I said, the minigui actually displays the command line you need... why don't you use that, rather than trying to brute-force guess?!?

Comment: Here is a list (for 0.7.1 though) of command line parameters, descriptions, and values: https://elki-project.github.io/releases/release0.7.1/doc/parameters-byopt.html but beware that these are context sensitive, so they may not always be available (e.g. DBSCAN options are only available if you use DBSCAN, obviously).

Comment: actaully i was confused between -dbc and -dbc.in. Still i am confused how to give argument for -dbc.in it will just file name or full path of file like c:\ etc. and where will i need to paste data file. Second question is if i use same parameters in minigui and cli which one in both will give better performance in context of runtime.

Comment: GUI has more overhead, so CLI will likely be marginally faster. File names are relative to your working directory (which you can configure!) or absolute.

Comment: In AbstractionRelation class on line 112 getKNNQuery is called when i press ctrl + T eclipse showing me more than 10 classes which implement KNNQuery interface. I want to know where is the implementation of getKNNQuery method?

Comment: Depends on what *index* you use. Because every index needs to implement the query differently. If you don't use an index, see further down, line 139.

Comment: i want to divide and  run linearScan method in different threads. can you please guide me how can i do this because i dont know the what relation and obj are doing in the method.

Comment: That will be a nontrivial task, because you need to handle synchronization of the threads properly. You can try to have a look at the parallelization code that already exists in ELKI. It's certainly not something I can explain in 500 characters here. Synchronization is hard. I would rather parallelize on a higher level, where you need less synchronization (because it is expensive).

Comment: It means only this linearscan method i can run in parallel by using and implementing already available elki parallelization code? For conversation we can talk using email ?

Comment: Sorry, I do not have the time to guide you. Synchronization will be a bottleneck (make sure you understand what that is), so the best approach usually is to do more than one query at a time. Look at the existing parallel LOF code, for example. Parallel programming is not something I could teach you in an email either, even if I had the time to do so. You need to use a book, and collect your own experiences.

Comment: Okay. I know about Synchronization.   Let me search and do some experiments first and than ask you about an issue if i had